# The application gets stuck at "Configuring OrikaBean mapper". Why?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot

**I have a spring-boot application and when I run the application, it gets stuck at "Configuring OrikaBean mapper...". Why ?**

> Note : It happens only when I run the application from eclipse.

*No issue happens when I run it externally from command prompt.*

**The console message :**

```
[36mm.m.ff.service.mapper.orika.OrikaBean [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Init OrikaBeanMapper
36mm.m.ff.service.mapper.orika.OrikaBean [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Configuring OrikaBean mapper...
```

Answer (score 0):

found the way as when running this "Configuring OrikaBean mapper...", it will consume quite a memory. So increase the hotspot memory setting will solve the issue. Drun.jvmArguments="-Xms2712m -Xmx2712m" when starting this on eclipse from the mvn command.